# Math Contest Question with Polynomials

Tags: functions, polynomials, contest-math

3. Prove that there does not exist a polynomial f(x) with integer coeﬃcients for which f(2008) = 0 and f(2010) = 1867.

This is a question from CMOQR (Qualifier for Canadian Math Olympiad , not the national Olympiad itself). This contest is from 2009 but they do not have solutions posted to it.

I had an idea to solve this problem but wasn't sure if it was logically correct.

I said to start with f(x) in the form: $f(x) = (a_0 + a_1x^1 + a_2x^2 + ... + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_nx^n)$ then convert it to $f(x) = a(x-2008)(b_0 + b_1x^1 + b_2x^2 + ... + b_{n-1}x^{n-1})$ since x = 2008 was a root of f(x). If I plug in x = 2010 into f(x), f(2010) would contain the linear term (x - 2008) = (2010 - 2008) = 2, which would in the product form of f(x) would lead to f(x) being even. Thus, f(2010) $\not=$ 1867 since 1867 is odd, not even.

Can anyone confirm if this is right? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your approach to the problem looks like a good one!

Comment: Note that the function has the same parity at both points. This is much easier to show than in your approach.  And we don't even need to do it in general. Since our test points is even, the parity is the parity of the constant term.

Comment: You do not need the $a$ in $f(x) = a(x-2008)(b_0 + \cdots)$, though it does no harm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(2008)=0$, the constant term is even. But then $f(2010)$ is even.

**Remark:** Yours is also a parity argument, and it is correct. It uses a little more machinery than necessary, and would require some modification if we had say $f(2008)=444$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, how would I prove the parity of polynomials?

Comment: It might be unnecessary to prove, it is so obvious. Or else $f(x)=a_0+xg(x)$ for some $g$ with integer coefficients. If $x$ is even, so is $xg(x)$, and therefore $f(x)$ has the same parity as $a_0$. Or else you can use congruence notation.

Comment: Was it the COMC or the Repechage?

Comment: It was the Repechage. I couldn't find the solutions for 2009 contest. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, and may things go well in any contest you take part in.

Answer (score 4):

For any polynomial with integer coefficients and any integer $x$, $f(x+2) \equiv f(x) \mod 2$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a generally useful fact that $(m-n) \mid f(m)-f(n)$ for any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. We can apply this here:

Suppose that $f(2008)=0$ and $f(2010)=1867$. But then $2 \mid 1867$, which is false.